# Iterar distintos bucles for en 1?

Tags: python

Tengo este código:

```
for k, v in redirections.items():
    new_id = list(filter(lambda a: v == a.dialog.peer.channel_id, dialogs))[0].id
    redirections[k] = new_id

for a, b in redirections2.items():
    new_id2 = list(filter(lambda a: b == a.dialog.peer.channel_id, dialogs))[0].id
    redirections2[a] = new_id2

for c, d in redirections3.items():
    new_id3 = list(filter(lambda a: d == a.dialog.peer.channel_id, dialogs))[0].id
    redirections3[c] = new_id3
```

Me gustaría poder iterar los 3 bucles en uno solo, ya que me parece demasiado redundante, he intentado realizarlo con ifs. Pero no terminar de funcionar bien el bucle. 
Redirections(2 y 3) son 3 diccionarios que tengo en un archivo de configuración, y el lambda simplemente comprueba que los datos que le llegan en "dialog.peer.channel_id, concuerda con lo que tiene en los diccionarios y si así, lo añade.

Con lo cual yo creo que es bastante redundante y me gustaría simplificarlo.

Alguien me podría dar alguna indicación, se agradece la ayuda.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Ver **Actualización** al final, para la respuesta a lo enunciado en un comentario por el usuario)

En el módulo `itertools` tienes la función `chain`, pensada para encadenar varios iterables de forma *lazy* (es decir, sin tener que generar y almacenar en memoria las listas de cada iterable para poder sumarlas).

Ejemplo:

```
d1 = { "a": 1, "b": 2}
d2 = { "b": 3, "c": 4}
d3 = { "a": 2, "b": 5, "f": 6}

from itertools import chain

for k,v in chain(d1.items(), d2.items(), d3.items()):
  print(k,v)
```

Imprime

```
a 1
b 2
b 3
c 4
a 2
b 5
f 6
```

### Versión con programación funcional

Sé lo que estás pensando. Eso de `d1.items(), d2.items(), d3.items()` es una repetición que "huele un poco mal". Quizás podría evitarse.

Por ejemplo, ¿y si todos los diccionarios estuvieran en una lista, por ejemplo `datos = [d1, d2, d3]`? ¿Cómo invocar `.items()`en cada elemento aplicar `chain()` al resultado?

Una forma sencilla es usar una *expresión generadora* para aplicar `.item()`, y el operador de desempaquetado `*` para convertir el iterable resultante en una serie de parámetros para `chain()`. Así:

```
datos = [d1, d2, d3]
for k,v in chain(*(d.items() for d in datos)):
  print(k,v)
```

Esta es para mi la forma más legible y pythonica. Pero que sepas que Python también soporta el paradigma de programación funcional, aunque para mi gusto la sintaxis se vuelve más ofuscada. Aunque a los matemáticos suele gustarles más esto:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import methodcaller
from functools import partial

getitems = partial(methodcaller("items"))

for k, v in chain(*map(getitems, datos)):
  print(k,v)
```

Si a alguien le interesa que explique cómo funciona esto, puede dejar un comentario.

## Actualización

Perdón. Tan centrado estaba en la pregunta de cómo "concatenar" los diccionarios para iterar sobre ellos, que ni me fijé que durante el bucle se estaban modificando esos diccionarios.

De entrada una nota sobre modificar iterables mientras se itera sobre ellos. Está *prohibido* (no estrictamente, pero el resultado es imprevisible) añadir o eliminar elementos al iterable mientras se itera por él. Sin embargo este no es el caso en la pregunta del usuario, que lo que hace es modificar el valor almacenado en las claves.

Eso sí es seguro, pero los mecanismos basados en `chain()` no son aplicables, pues con estos mecanismos tenemos sólo las claves y los valores, pero no las referencias a los diccionarios originales para poder cambiar elementos.

Por suerte la solución es tremendamente sencilla. De hecho, esta misma solución sería usable aún si no se cambian los elementos y por tanto es una alternativa al `chain()`, y a lo propuesto en otras respuestas. ¡Basta hacer un bucle anidado! Uno itera por los diccionarios y el otro por los elementos de cada diccionario.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código cambia el valor almacenado en cada clave de cada diccionario por el doble del valor que había:

```
for d in (d1, d2, d3):
  for k,v in d.items():
    d[k] = 2*v
```

En tu caso:

```
for d in (redirections, redirections2, redirections3):
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_id = list(filter(lambda a: v == a.dialog.peer.channel_id, dialogs))[0].id
        d[k] = new_id
```

**Nota al margen** El `list(filter(...))` puede cambiarse por una *list comprehension* que en opinión de muchos (incluído Guido) es más legible:

```
new_id = [a for a in dialogs if a.dialog.peer.channel_id==v][0].id
```

Comment: Vale, lo he intentado aplicar, pero hay una cosa que no tengo muy clara, edito mi pregunta.

Comment: @Peisou He leido tu anterior comentario y he actualizado la respuesta, con una solución mucho más sencilla

Comment: Vale, ahora si!!! muchas gracias, ojala pudiera dar dos respuestas como validas, justo iba a editar mi post ahora, pero al final no sera necesario, me ha quedado clarisimo, muchas gracias de verdad. :)

Answer (score 2):

claro, puedes juntar las listas y luego iterar solo una lista:

```
for a,b in redirections.items() + redirections2.items() + redirections3.items():
    ...
```

Comment: Esto no funciona (al menos en Python3). `dict.items()` retorna un objeto de tipo `dict_items()` para el que la suma no está definida. Tendrías que poner un `list()` alrededor de cada uno para poder "sumarlos".

Answer (score 2):

Si las claves son distintas entre los diccionarios, una forma es "unir" los tres en un solo y recorrerlo una sola vez.

A partir de Python 3.5 puedes hacer esto:

```
redirections = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
redirections2 = {"c": 3, "d": 4}
redirections3 = {"e": 5, "f": 6}

for a, b in {**redirections, **redirections2, **redirections3}.items():
  print(a,b)
```

Si hay claves repetidas entre los diccionarios, solo obtendrás una de ellas.

Comment: He probado tu manera y me funciona a la perfeccion, ya que al no necesitar una lista, puedo meter directamente los datos a los diferentes diccionarios. Muchas gracias!!